# .NET primitives and type hierarchies, why was it designed like this?

Tags: c#, .net, primitive

I would like to understand why on .NET there are nine integer types: `Char`, `Byte`, `SByte`, `Int16`, `UInt16`, `Int32`, `UInt32`, `Int64`, and `UInt64`; plus other numeric types: `Single`, `Double`, `Decimal`; and all these types have no relation at all.

When I first started coding in C# I thought "cool, there's a `uint` type, I'm going to use that when negative values are not allowed". Then I realized no API used `uint` but `int` instead, and that `uint` is not derived from `int`, so a conversion was needed.

What are the real world application of these types? Why not have, instead, `integer` and `positiveInteger` ? These are types I can understand. A person's age in years is a `positiveInteger`, and since `positiveInteger` is a subset of `integer` there's so need for conversion whenever `integer` is expected.

The following is a diagram of the type hierarchy in XPath 2.0 and XQuery 1.0. If you look under `xs:anyAtomicType` you can see the numeric hierarchy `decimal` > `integer` > `long` > `int` > `short` > `byte`. Why wasn't .NET designed like this? Will the new framework "Oslo" be any different?

[image]

Comment: About uint not in API's, take a look at the CLS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be because the underlying hardware breaks that class hierarchy.  There are (perhaps surprisingly) many times when you care that a `UInt32` is a 4 bytes big and unsigned, so a `UInt32` **is not** a kind of `Int32`, nor is an `Int32` a type of  `Int64`.

And you almost always care about the difference between an `int` and a `float`.

Fundamentally, inheritance & the class hierarchy are not the same as mathematical set inclusion.  The fact that the values a `UInt32` can hold are a strict subset of the values an `Int64` can hold does not mean that a `UInt32` is a type of `Int64`.  Less obviously, an `Int32` is not a type of `Int64` - even though there's no conceptual difference between them, their underlying representations are different (4 bytes versus 8 bytes).  `Decimals` are even more different.

XPath is different: the representations for all the numeric types are fundamentally the same - a string of ASCII digits.  There, the difference between a `short` and a `long` is one of *possible* range rather than representation - "123" is both a valid representation of a `short` and a valid representation of a `long` with the same value.

Comment: can you elaborate on 'underlying hardware breaks that class hierarchy'?

Comment: Conceptually, the hierarchy in your diagram is correct - a byte is a subset of short is a subset of int, etc.  This works for XPath, since it's dealing with XML, where the value 123 could be represented by the byte "123", the short "123", or the long "123" - the representations are exactly the same.  Here, the type is a constraint on the possible values, but doesn't change the representation.

For C#, the value 123 can be represented in memory as the byte, 0111 1011, the short 0000 0000 0111 1011, the int...  These representations are a different size, and the hardware has to care about that.

Comment: I see. Then, why do we need different representations? is it to make programs more efficient?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely to make programs more efficient.

You could store everything in an Int64, but then all your integer values would take up 8 bytes - incurring a memory penalty, and potentially a large runtime penalty.  I'm not sure if IA32 has instructions for 64bit * 64bit -> 64bit multiplication, for example, and even if it does, those 64bit values take up 2 registers each.

The different integer & float types are a(n important) part of the low-level architecture that C# decided shouldn't be abstracted away.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I wish I could program on a higher level, I thought C# was high enough. I'm happy to know now that the "M" language does have a numeric type hierarchy: Number > Decimal > Integer > Unsigned. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285273.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Decimal is intended for calculations that need precision (basically, money).
See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx

Singles/Doubles are different to decimals, because they're intended to be an approximation (basically, for scientific calculations).

That's why they're not related.

As for bytes and chars, they're totally different: a byte is 0-255, whereas a char is a character, and can hence store unicode characters (there are a lot more than 255 of them!)

Uints and ints don't convert automatically, because they can each store values that are impossible for the other (uints have twice the positive range of ints).

Once you get the hang of it all, it actually does make a lot of sense.

As for your ages thing, i'd simply use an int ;)

Comment: I understand why these numeric types are not related, my question is, why was .NET designed like this? I'm starting to think it's for compatibility with RDBMS. Do you use uint in your apps?

Comment: Never had the need to use uint personally. And if you're ever wondering 'why was feature X in .net designed like this?' the usual answer is 'because its like that in Java' ;)

Comment: One reason that int is often used over uint is that uint is not compliant with the Common Language Specification.

Comment: Decimal does NOT have "unlimited accuracy and length". Decimal arithmetic is approximate, not exact. The difference between decimal and double is that they have different values that can be represented without error, different precisions, and different ranges.

Comment: I'll be jiggered - you're right! I must have been getting it mixed up with ruby's big numbers: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(VS.80).aspx